# C# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I am getting this "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" message but almost after 6 hours trying i decide to ask it here.

My code below. I tried all the recommendations like using `UseDefaultCredentials = true;` or `PreAuthenticate = true;` or `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;` but no luck.

I check to see if my credentials are not correct but that's not the case. I am able to access the url from browser. It's using basic authentication.

So i'm out of ideas. Any idea what i am missing here?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string myno = "1238239202";
    string url = string.Format(@"https://myurl.com/get?doc_type1=number&response=T&no_id={0}", myno);
    string userName = @"myusernanme";
    string password = "mypassword";    
    string fileDownloadUrl = string.Format(@"C:\users\{0}\Desktop\folder\{1}.tiff", userName, myno);

    Stream stream = HttpWebResponseStream(url, userName, password);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] myResultArray = content.Split('|');
    url = myResultArray[19];

    //Download File
    stream = HttpWebResponseStream(url, userName, password);

    using (FileStream output = new FileStream(fileDownloadUrl, FileMode.Create))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(output);
    }

    stream.Dispose();
}

static Stream HttpWebResponseStream(string url, string userName, string password)
{
    HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

    WebResponse response = http.GetResponse();

    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: What kind of authentication does the API actually use? Kerberos / Windows? Or HTTP Basic? Or something else? You need to know that first before we can fix anything.

Comment: It's using basic authentication. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't access this url address without loging in. You can access the url via your browser because you have cookie or access token on your browser and previously you logged in. You can't access this url by providing user name and password. You have to provide access token which is set on your cookie or browser storage in your request header. Check you browser to find the token and the name of the header.

Comment: I dont think this is the case. I can access the url with Python as well.